# Passing Bash Shell Variable to Awk NR function

Tags: bash, awk

I wish to loop through a M row X N column array of values and print them to the screen to be used for a later script, but I am having trouble with the loop and NR.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat temp_file | wc -l > num_rows
i="0"
while [ $i -le `cat num_rows` ]; do
    echo $i
    awk 'NR==$i{print $1, $2}' temp_file
    awk 'NR==$i{print $3, $4}' temp_file
    ((i++))
done
```

As you can see, I wish to use first find the number of lines, num_rows, and loop through each of those rows, and use AWK's NR function to go through each row and print columns one and two first, then columns three and four.  The following error results when the above script runs:

```
0
awk: illegal field $(), name "i"
 input record number 1, file temp_file
 source line number 1
awk: illegal field $(), name "i"
 input record number 1, file temp_file
 source line number 1
1
awk: illegal field $(), name "i"
 input record number 1, file temp_file
 source line number 1
awk: illegal field $(), name "i"
 input record number 1, file temp_file
 source line number 1
2
awk: illegal field $(), name "i"
 input record number 1, file temp_file
 source line number 1
awk: illegal field $(), name "i"
 input record number 1, file temp_file
 source line number 1
3
awk: illegal field $(), name "i"
 input record number 1, file temp_file
 source line number 1
awk: illegal field $(), name "i"
 input record number 1, file temp_file
 source line number 1
4
```

and so on until the while loop completes.  Any thoughts on how to fix this script, because right now, setting NR==$i does not work.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Couldn't the whole script be replaced by `awk '{ print $3, $4 }' temp_file`?

Comment: I've edited the above script.  I need to call awk twice, first to print out the first two columns, then again to print the second two columns

Comment: Couldn't the whole script be replaced by `awk '{ print $1, $2; print $3, $4 }' temp_file`?

Comment: Sorry.  I apologize for not being clear.  I need to just work with the output from each row, because I will take this logic and send the output to a temp file that'll be used in another part of the script.  So, I just want to work with each row rather than printing all columns from each row at once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass `i` to awk by

```
awk -v i=$i 'NR==i{print $1, $2}' temp_file
```

or

```
awk 'NR=='$i'{print $1, $2}' temp_file
```

Comment: Thank you slitvinov.  That was my issue: passing a shell variable to the NR value.  Thanks for your help.  I'll change title.